# Scrape a web page which uses custom font using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, truetype

I am trying to scrape this [webpage](http://www.vidyavrikshah.org/literature/sankara/siva1.html) which uses a custom font to present text in Sanskrit. I have the ttf file for the font used in the webpage.

Is there anyway I could scrape this website using ttf file and encode the content to unicode using Python (if not, any language)?

The font they are using is `iitmsans.ttf` from http://www.acharya.gen.in:8080/fonts/iitmfonts.php

Comment: The TTF file doesn't reveal which Unicode code points these glyphs map to. You will need to create a table which contains a mapping from each character code to its corresponding Unicode code point (also known as an encoding).

Comment: For what it's worth, the page renders simply as ½£   ÂO¤âÔOOd[kOÛOÓdÓOØO¯  etc for me.

Comment: Is this supposed to represent Devanagari? Any chance that it's actually using (something like) [ISCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#ISCII) or some other existing encoding?

Comment: The text is devanagari. It is using iitmsans fonts.

Comment: http://www.acharya.gen.in:8080/fonts/iitmfonts.php says they are using a custom encoding which is supposed to be compatible with ISO-8859-1. They are a non-profit so ideally they would have a public document with information about the encoding. Otherwise you will have to reconstruct the encoding by hand. I repeat, having the font doesn't help at all (except you can render a map to help you see what the glyphs look like so you can try to find them in a Unicode chart).

Comment: I ran [`ttx`](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) on the font and it seems to contain the supremely useless ISO-8859-1 names of the glyphs instead of any indication of what they represent in their custom encoding. I can't read Devanagari so I'm probably not particularly competent to identify the glyphs but if you can generate a simple table it's probably approx 30 minutes of work for someone who is familiar with the script (or say 60 for a slow typist, to avoid overoptimistic estimates). For tangential inspiration, maybe see also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @tripleee for information. But the output from the Wikipedia's ISCII table is gibberish. Is there any way I can use the Glyphs produced by the http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/ to convert the text to unicode?

Answer (score 0):

No, you probably have to do a bit of manual work to create an encoding for Python.  The TTF file doesn't contain information about the Unicode mappings [(it *could*](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-chapter08#05931f9d) but it's uncommon, and this one doesn't).

Looking at the font in http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/ I see many Devanagari glyphs but I don't know their names or what variations are common or permitted in drawing them so I probably can't easily find the same glyphs in Unicode for you.  But I recognize the "om" glyph [U+0950](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0950/index.htm) on character code 65 (0x41) so I can contribute the first item in your encoding:

```
{
 # ...
 0x41: '\u0950',
 # ...
}
```

Do this for all the other glyphs in the font and you have a mapping you can use in Python.  The general guidance is in the documentation for the standard [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module, but probably you want to find examples like [Custom Python Charmap Codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230733/custom-python-charmap-codec) too.

[image: Screen dump of OM glyph]

Comment: Thanks a lot @tripleee for your help. I have one last doubt. How do I convert the text to character code so that I can convert that to Unicode using my mapper?

Comment: The text on the page *is* characters, you just need (to construct) a codec to `decode` them to Unicole.

Comment: If you can provide a text table with the mappings, we can probably figure out the rest between us. If you are on Github, a gist with the first few would be a good start.