# codec can't encode character python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the name and price from this website:

https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2

Both name and price are within `div` tags.

**Name:**

[image]

**Price**

[image]

Printing name works fine, but printing Price gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\File.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(price.text)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniq")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
    print(name.text)
```

[image]

What is the difference between those?

So why one of them give me an error and the other one is not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and BeautifulSoup encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues)

Comment: Which version of Python? You might have better luck with 3.6 or later.

Comment: Python version is 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is yielding that error because python is having trouble with that currency sign. The Indian rupee sign is interpreted differently [depending on the language](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm) and is not in the python charmap by default. If we change your last print statement to `print(str(price.text.encode("utf-8")))` we will get results that look like this:

`b'\xe2\x82\xb961,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb940,000'
b'\xe2\x82\xb963,854'
b'\xe2\x82\xb934,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb948,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb952,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb932,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb954,990'
b'\xe2\x82\xb952,990'`

Since this output isn't very pretty and probably isn't usable, I would personally truncate that symbol before printing. If you really want python to print the Indian rupee symbol, you can add it to your charmap. Follow this steps from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230733/custom-python-charmap-codec) to add customizations to the charmap.